# How to delete a contact?

Tags: wordpress

I just imported csv file, with organization as the contact type. I filled in all the ncessary fields and it shows that I have 0 errors and able to import all the 213 rows. However, after I import, I am only able to find 1 contact and I cant delete this contact. The message will prompt that the contact is used for some special administrative purposes. May I check how i can go about deleting this contact as well as finding all the imported contact?

Comment: A subset of the import .csv, with headers and anonymized data, would be helpful to clarify what's going on. Same for screen snippets of the submission and results pages. Finally, a snippet with a search that should find contacts in the sample data. Contact import is hugely important. If you've found a problem there, it is worth ample documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This 1 contact you can not delete (usually the contact with ID 1) is the Drupal administrator account and this can not be deleted as it is the "owner" of the installation.

I can not from a distance see what happened with your import. You should be able to see imported contacts when using the Search>Find contacts option.

If you can not find any contacts you could check the civicrm_contact table but you should really have received an error message in your import?